# Using task queue to parse large xml data

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

So what I'm trying to do is go through a 5Gb xml file of products for a website and eventually add the data to a datastore. I'm just playing around with queues now and my idea was to create a queue that will read through the file line by line and take every 50 products and send them to another queue to be processed (eventually to the datastore). I'm testing this on a much smaller xml file. My problem is within OpenFileQueue, it's creating a queue even when the conditions "if ((self.count % 50) == 0):" have not been met. Any ideas on what might be going on? Or ideas on better ways to read through this file. It feels like a bad hack the way im doing it now. The test file im using has around 170 products when I run the code as it is now and call /gcs I end up with about 86 queues. Not sure what is going on here.

```
import webapp2
import os
import datetime
import time
from lxml import etree
import sys
import codecs
import time
import gc
import logging


from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import search
import cloudstorage as gcs
from google.appengine.api import taskqueue

my_default_retry_params = gcs.RetryParams(initial_delay=0.2,
                                      max_delay=5.0,
                                      backoff_factor=2,
                                      max_retry_period=15)
gcs.set_default_retry_params(my_default_retry_params)

logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


class GoogleCloudStorage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        bucket = '/newegg-catalog'
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.tmp_filenames_to_clean_up = []    
        filename = bucket + '/ndd.xml'     
        taskqueue.add(url='/openfile', params={'filename': filename})
        self.redirect('/')



class AddFileParts(webapp2.RequestHandler):
     def post(self):
         data = self.request.get('data')
         logging.debug('PROCESSING %s', data)

class OpenFileQueue(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, request, response):
        self.initialize(request, response)
        self.Plist = []
        self.masterList = []
        self.count = 0

    def post(self):
        filename = self.request.get('filename')
        logging.debug('Opening file %s', filename)
        gcs_file = gcs.open(filename)

        while True:
            line = gcs_file.readline()
            self.Plist.append(line)
            if line.strip()=="</product>":
                self.masterList.append(self.Plist)
                self.Plist = []
                self.count+=1

            if ((self.count % 50) == 0):
                logging.debug('Starting queue of items up to %s with 50 items', self.count)
                taskqueue.add(url='/adddata', params={'data': self.masterList})
                self.masterList = []
            if line.strip()=="</catalog>":
                break
        gcs_file.close()

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/adddata',AddFileParts),
                                ('/openfile', OpenFileQueue),
                                ('/gcs', GoogleCloudStorage)],
                                debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

When a line matches `"</product>"`, it appends to `self.masterlist` and increments `self.count` (eventually to 50).  But if the next line is not `"</product>"`, the count will still be 50 and add another task to the queue.

Instead, use the length of `self.masterList` because it is reset after being added to the queue:

```
if len(self.masterList) >= 50:
    logging.debug('Starting queue of items up to %s with 50 items', len(self.masterList))
    taskqueue.add(url='/adddata', params={'data': self.masterList})
    self.masterList = []
```

and remove all references to `self.count`.